# Storing external claims

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I login using google authentication in the startup I can get the access token.

Startup:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "",
    ClientSecret = "",
    Scope = { "" },
    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnAuthenticated = async context =>
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("googletoken", context.AccessToken));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.Name, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, context.Email, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"));
        }
    }
});
```

My custom claim manager:

```
public class ClaimManager
{
    private readonly ClaimsIdentity _user;

    public ClaimManager(ClaimsIdentity user)
    {
        this._user = user;
    }
    public static string GetAccessToken(ClaimsIdentity user)
    {
        var claim = user.Claims.Select(c => new { Type = c.Type, Value = c.Value }).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "googletoken");
        return claim == null ? null : claim.Value;
    }
    public static string GetName(ClaimsIdentity user)
    {
        var claim = user.Claims.Select(c => new { Type = c.Type, Value = c.Value }).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name");
        return claim == null ? null : claim.Value;
    }
    public static string GetEmail(ClaimsIdentity user)
    {
        var claim = user.Claims.Select(c => new { Type = c.Type, Value = c.Value }).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress");
        return claim == null ? null : claim.Value;
    }
}
```

The access token is not persisted in the user claims. How can I persist claims so that they stay in the user session?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with. I am storing the access token just like a regular claim in the database.

In account controller:

```
public async Task StoreAccessToken(ExternalLoginInfo loginInfo)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
    if (user != null)
    {
        var newClaim = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.Select(c => new Claim(c.Type, c.Value)).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "googletoken");

        if (newClaim != null)
        {
            var userClaims = await UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(user.Id);
            foreach (var userClaim in userClaims.Where(c => c.Type == newClaim.Type).ToList())
                await UserManager.RemoveClaimAsync(user.Id, userClaim);

            await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, newClaim);
        }
    }
}
```

ExternalLoginCallback():

```
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    await StoreAccessToken(loginInfo);
```

ExternalLoginConfirmation():

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        await StoreAccessToken(info);
        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally, an answer I can follow!